# Mockito.doNothing() is still running

Tags: testing, gwt, mockito

I'm trying to test small pieces of code. I do not want test one of the method and used Mockito.doNothing(), but this method was still run. How can I do that?

```
 protected EncoderClientCommandEventHandler clientCommandEventHandlerProcessStop = new EncoderClientCommand.EncoderClientCommandEventHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onCommandPerformed(
        EncoderClientCommand clientCommand) {
      setWatcherActivated(false);
      buttonsBackToNormal();
    }
  };

  protected void processStop() {
    EncoderServerCommand serverCommand = new EncoderServerCommand();
    serverCommand.setAction(EncoderAction.STOP);

    checkAndSetExtension();
    serverCommand.setKey(getArchiveJobKey());
    getCommandFacade().performCommand(
        serverCommand,
        EncoderClientCommand.getType(),
        clientCommandEventHandlerProcessStop);
  }

  @Test
  public void testClientCommandEventHandlerProcessStop() {
    EncoderClientCommand encoderClientCommand = mock(EncoderClientCommand.class);

    Mockito.doNothing().when(encoderCompositeSpy).buttonsBackToNormal();

    when(encoderCompositeSpy.isWatcherActivated()).thenReturn(false);
    encoderCompositeSpy.clientCommandEventHandlerProcessStop.onCommandPerformed(encoderClientCommand);
```

Comment: Could you give a piece of code that can compile? Your naming doesn't seem to be consistent atm.

Comment: Can you confirm that EncoderComposite.buttonsBackToNormal() is public and non-final?

Comment: buttonsBackToNormal() is protected void

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. One of the variable is already mocked in buttonsBackNormal().